# Access to csv file in jar

Tags: java, file, embedded-resource

I tried everything to access to csv file when a run my jar.
I put the csv in resources package in Eclipse, and it's fine when I run the code from this, but it doesn't work when I run the jar from an executable.

```
ClassLoader c = MyClass.class.getClassLoader();
URL url = c.getResource("com/mysoft/resources/");
String path = URLDecoder.decode(url.getPath(), "utf-8");
File f = new File(path+ "VAL.csv");
if(f.exists())
...
```

I don't want to put this file out of the jar. I just want read the file, how can I do ?

Comment: A File object represents the path of a file on the file system. Your csv is not on the file system. It's inside the jar. Use ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(csvPath), and read from the returned stream.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to read the file, you can do this:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(csvPath)));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

Comment: can you please clear what is the `csvpath` in this ? I am facing same problem as discuss in above question but when i use the `InputStreamReader` it shows `NullPointerException`

Comment: `csvPath` is the path relative to the root of your jar file. So if the file is in some base directory called "dir", you'd want `csvPath = "/dir/file.csv"`

Answer (score 1):

Use getResourceAsStream and you should specify the encoding whenever possible.  Try this:

```
in = new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(
         new BufferedInputStream(
           this.getResourceAsStream("myPackage/myFile.txt")),
         "UTF-8"));
```