# Access to csv file in jar without InputStream

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jar

I tried everything to access to CSV file when a run my jar. I put the CSV in resources package in Eclipse, and it's fine when I run the code from there, but it doesn't work when I run the jar from an executable.

```
ClassLoader c = MyClass.class.getClassLoader();
URL url = c.getResource("com/mysoft/resources/");
String path = URLDecoder.decode(url.getPath(), "utf-8");
File f = new File(path+ "VAL.csv");
if(f.exists())
...
```

I don't want to put this file out of the jar. I just want read the file. How can I do it?

EDIT: I closed my login of my first post - [Access to csv file in jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248906/access-to-csv-file-in-jar) - and I don't know how to remove it, and I can't respond to comments. So I posted it again here.

Is it possible not to use InputStream ?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid using an InputSTream, since that's precisely what you must use to read your CSV? You already had an answer to your previous, identical question. Use this answer. If you're still stuck, then answer to the comments, edit your question to show what you have tried. And provide more information: what does the jar contain, for example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access to csv file in jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248906/access-to-csv-file-in-jar)

Comment: Because I already have method which read csv out of jar, and I would like to use the same with csv inside jar

Comment: So, make this method take an InputStream as argument, and call it either with the InputStream returned by `ClassLoader.gerResourceAsStream()` (when the file is inside the jar), or with a FileInputStream (when the file is on the filesystem). There's no way to use a File for a resource inside a jar (other than reading the resource and write it to a file, and then reopen this file, which is stupid)

Comment: Ok, it's work with InputStream, I'm going to change my code to use it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of getResource() here is very dubious. I would not rely on getResource() finding a packet/directory at all (after all, one can argue that it should return resources, not namespaces).

Also, *never ever* interpret the URL returned by getResource() - its inviting trouble times two. The ClassLoader can return you anything, the URL returned *may* have nothing in common with what you asked for. Constructing something from the URL's String representation has an abhorrent opportunity of failure when the ClassLoader isn't your standard classpath JRE classloader (think of Application Server, WebStart etc.).

Ask *directly* for the Resource you want:

```
 getResource("com/mysoft/resources/VAL.csv")
```

And *don't* create a *File*, use InputStream. Resources *aren't files*, you can not access them with File API.